# use of ?? to get attributes of an object if the object isn't null

Tags: c#, operators, isnull

Is it possible to use C# '??' operator as this :

```
var _var = pr.Value ?? "NA";
```

To check if pr is null and not if Value attribute of pr is null ?

I don't find any example that show something like this.

If yes, is it recommanded  or is it better to use extension method in this case ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Comment: what problem do you have with this code? Did you try it out? If `pr.Value` is a string, this should work as is.

Comment: @AccessDenied I already had a look at the Null -coalescing and I don't really find if my case was possible or not.

Comment: @HimBromBeere My example wasn't the most explicit one probably but in my case Value isn't a String. Sorry I should have taken something else than just "NA"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To check if **pr is null** and **not if Value attribute of pr is null** ?

Seems like you only want to check if `pr` is null. in which case ternary operator is your option:

```
var _var = pr == null ? "NA" : pr.Value;
```

or use a simple `if`/`else`.

Comment: With the introduction of C# 7, `is null` is *slightly* better to use than `== null` in the general case, as this will never use operator overloads, it will always just do a reference check (for reference types).

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I didn't know that.. insightful indeed and I'll keep that in mind from now on. I'll leave my answer as is since you've already posted that solution. appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 different scenarios here so let's go through the syntax for each:

1. Return `"NA"` if *either* `pr` or `pr.Value` is null:

   ```
   var _var = pr?.Value ?? "NA";
   ```

   The `?.` operator will basically say that "if `pr` is null, return null for the whole expression and do not dereference `pr.Value`"

   So if `pr` is null, the `?.` operator will make the expression evaluate to null, or if `pr.Value` is null, it will also evaluate to null, and in both cases, `?? "NA"` will evaluate the whole thing to `"NA"`.

   This is result-wise equivalent to this:

   ```
   string _var;
   if (pr is null || pr.Value is null)
       _var = "NA";
   else
       _var = pr.Value;
   ```
2. Return `"NA"` if `pr.Value` is null:

   ```
   var _var = pr.Value ?? "NA";
   ```

   This is what you have. This will throw a `NullReferenceException` if `pr` is null, but evaluate to `"NA"` if `pr` is non-null but `pr.Value` is null.

   This is result-wise equivalent to this:

   ```
   string _var;
   if (pr.Value is null) // can throw NullReferenceException
       _var = "NA";
   else
        _var = pr.Value;
   ```
3. Return `"NA"` if `pr` is null and ... what if `pr.Value` is null?

   Neither `??` nor `?.` can help you here but you can use the ternary operator:

   ```
   var _var = (pr is null)
       ? "NA"
       : pr.Value;
   ```

   This will evaluate to `"NA"` if `pr` is null, `pr.Value` if `pr` is non-null, which will thus be able to evaluate to null if `pr` is non-null but `pr.Value` is null.

---

**Note**, the `??` operator is also evaluated lazily, just as the ternary operator, so if you have this:

```
var _v = pr?.Value ?? ComputeTheValue();
```

and that method call is expensive, it will only be evaluated if `pr?.Value` is actually null, if `pr` is non-null and `pr.Value` is non-null, the call will not be made.